# xhtml2pdf how manage the class attribute?

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

In my django project i have to create a pdf file from my html.
For this purpose i use xhtml2pdf and in my html  section i write:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#FAFAFA;font:8pt "Tahoma";}
    * {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
    th, td {border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;}

    @page { 
        size: a4 portrait;
        margin: 1cm auto;
        padding: 1cm;
        margin: 1cm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     }

    table {
        -pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    p {margin:0;padding:0;line-height:1.4em}
    .column-50-left {width:49.5%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;padding-right:15px}
    .column-50-right {width:49.5%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;padding-left:15px}
    .invoice {font-size:6pt}
    .invoice td {height:50px;vertical-align:top;padding:5px;}
    .destinatario td {height:120px;vertical-align:top;padding:5px;font-size:6pt}
    .description th {height: 30px}
    .description td {height: 50px}
    .top-10 {margin-top:10px}
    .top-15 {margin-top:15px}
    .top-20 {margin-top:20px}
    .padding-top-4 {padding-top:4px}
    .padding-bottom-15 {padding-bottom:15px}
    .padding-bottom-30 {padding-bottom:30px}
    .border-top {border-top:1px solid #000000}

</style>
```

but when i use my  attributes on elements for apply the styles nothing appen for example:

```
<table style="width:80%" class="invoice top-10">
```

or

```
<div class="border-top top-10 invoice padding-top-4 padding-bottom-15"><p>PORTO / <em>Freight</em></p></div>
```

How can i apply my class style to my pdf output in xhtml2pdf?

So many thanks in advance